# NetSuite - Color Fields Based On Value

Tags: colors, field, netsuite

On a basic (custom) form, is there any way I can change the color of a label depending on the value of the field?

We have an ***Inactive*** box near the top of the form and I'd like to be able to make it red (and bold, and larger font) when it's checked. I believe I could do it by dynamically changing the form, but that's a lot of overhead and not a great user experience.

Answer (score 1):

DOM manipulation is discouraged and not supported by NetSuite, but it's your only option. There are no native APIs for changing label colors.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to add another field of type inline html or rich text, and update that field with a client script or user event based on the value of the inactive field.